# Get ID of Clicked element class and return this ID as Value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently learning some Javascript.

I have come to the DOM manipulation point however I am stuck searching on how to solve the following:

I have 4 images with the same class and want to return their ID based on the image clicked by the user.
I want to store this ID as a variable and then compare with some other data.

I believe I should be using event listeners but I can figure out how to return the ID and store its value to further compare this value within other functions.

HTML

```html
<img id="blue" class="bubble" src="Images/bubble-blue.png">
<img id="green" class="bubble" src="Images/bubble-green.png">
<img id="pink" class="bubble" src="Images/bubble-pink.png">
<img id="purple" class="bubble" src="Images/bubble-purple.png">
```

so as per the images, i want to determine which bubble was clicked and compare with a bubble selected by the computer.

so I want to create a function which will return the ID either blue/pink/purple/green as a value.

Comment: Not real clear what you are asking. Maybe [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)?

Comment: Are images wrapped in a div or other element?

Comment: yes, I have them wrapped! :>)

Answer (score 2):

You can get information about the element that triggered a specific event listener by reading the associated event's [`Event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) property:

```js
// apply the event listener to all images
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener('click', event => {
    // event variable has `currentTarget` attribute, which is a reference to the object that triggered the listener
    // in this context, you can use it in place of a similar call to something like document.querySelector(), etc.
    const imageId = event.currentTarget.id;
    // do whatever processing you need on the `id` string by referencing `imageId`
    console.log(imageId);
  });
});
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" id="kitten1" />
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" id="kitten2" />
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" id="kitten3" />
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" id="kitten4" />
```

Alternative version, added by @connexo:

```js
const kittens = document.querySelectorAll('img.kitten'); // get a collection of kitten images
for (const kitten of kittens) { // iterate over the collection
  kitten.addEventListener('click', () => { // add a click listener to each kitten
    console.log(kitten.id); // log that kitten's id when the kitten gets clicked
  });
};
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" id="kitten1" class="kitten" />
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" id="kitten2" class="kitten" />
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" id="kitten3" class="kitten" />
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" id="kitten4" class="kitten" />
```

Comment: If the listener is attached directly to the images as in your example, I'd use `event.target` since images cannot have descendants. To read their `id`, use the corresponding property `element.id` instead of the attribute.

Comment: @connexo Hm, not sure I agree re: `event.target` vs. `currentTarget`, but I can be convinced. Would you agree that it'd be better practice long-term to use `currentTarget` to avoid the problem of getting information on the descendants of the node that the listener is applied to? As you mention it's not an issue in this case, but in my experience, most times the implementation is concerned solely with the element the listener was directly applied to.

Comment: Hi this exactly what I want to do, however my file has tons of images so I want to only select an specific class, is this possible with a class?

Comment: @DianaC Yeah, just change the selector in the argument to `querySelectorAll` to only target images with your specific class. `img.className` (See also: [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors))

Comment: @DianaC In your case, it's `document.querySelectorAll('img.bubble')`.

Comment: @esqew I have been authoring web components for the past 4 years and I've never had any case where I would want `currentTarget` over  `target`.

Comment: @connexo I appreciate your viewpoint, but I think I'll leave `currentTarget` in the answer in this particular case (even though we're really splitting hairs in this particular example).

Comment: Well especially in this example there can be no difference between the two.

Comment: Also I recommend to use `for...of` to iterate over iterables. It's easier to read, doesn't require a callback and it works for any iterable whereas `forEach` must live in the object's prototype.

Comment: I see the main problem was I was trying to use > querySelectorAll ('.bubble' ) instead of querySelectorAll('img.bubble') ahhhhhh

Comment: Thank you @esqew , I was really helpfull.

Comment: wait, but shouldnt it also work using   querySelectorAll ('.bubble' ) ?

Comment: @esqew I've added an addtional, alternative version (how I'd write it). If that bothers you, feel free to roll back the edit.

Comment: @DianaC As long as only the images you want to target have this class, yes.

Comment: @connexo No, looks great! Appreciate the edit considering the succinctness of your methodology.

Comment: Thanks @connexo , Maybe all my code is broken ... but thanks for the help, I think I can move on breaking my brain with my bubble game.

Comment: @esqew You're welcome. I've also been doing thorough code reviews the past 4 years, hence the suggestions.

Comment: @DianaC In case you want further help and the game is in a public repository feel free to add the URL into the question

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)?

```js
wrapper.onclick = e => {
  let el = e.target;
  if (el.className != "bubble") return;
  console.log(el.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img id="blue" class="bubble" src="https://placeimg.com/50/50/nature">
  <img id="green" class="bubble" src="https://placeimg.com/50/50/nature">
  <img id="pink" class="bubble" src="https://placeimg.com/50/50/nature">
  <img id="purple" class="bubble" src="https://placeimg.com/50/50/nature">
</div>
```